# Compiling HandleBars scripts in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: handlebars.js, visual-studio-2017

Is there any tooling support in VS2017 to pre-compile HandleBarsJs .hbs files in Visual Studio 2017? Web Essentials/[WebCompiler](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler) no longer appears to support this.

I am looking for an "easy" solution and would prefer not to have to install Node or something else to do this.